# How to check ESXi 5.0 LSI raid rebuild status

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware-raid, lsi

Product name: LSI SAS3041E

Is it possible to check the status of the rebuild? At the moment I only see that the raid is rebuilding/syncing from the lsi_log script, /var/log/vmkernel.log and vSphere status page. But i wonder how far that process is, and if it's somehow stuck somewhere. I would be nice to see the status in percentage.

Comment: ESXi 5.0?  Ouch.  Time to upgrade, man.

Answer (score 0):

If the software list nothing, then your last option is to enter the lsi utility at boot time. I dont warrant that it will show the %, as the software list nothing